# SQL Query - Show latest record only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a query that will pull a list of users that have run an in the past months but only show the last time they tried to launch. So if they launched the app 15 times I only want to see the most recent.  Currently the code I have is pulling a list of all the launches I just need help on how to weed out the ones I don't need.

```
SELECT [AccountName]
  ,[ApplicationName]
  ,[LaunchTime]
   FROM OurTable
   WHERE ApplicationName = 'Office13' 
   AND LaunchTime > DATEADD(MONTH,-9,GETDATE())
   GROUP BY LaunchTime, AccountName, ApplicationName
```

Comment: does the table have an ID for every record ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT  [AccountName]
  ,[ApplicationName]
  ,[LaunchTime]

   FROM OurTable ot1
   WHERE ApplicationName = 'Office13' 
   AND LaunchTime > DATEADD(MONTH,-9,GETDATE())   
   AND LaunchTime = (SELECT MAX(LaunchTime) FROM @OurTable ot2 WHERE ot2.AccountName = ot1.AccountName)
   GROUP BY AccountName, ApplicationName, LaunchTime
```

Comment: Using your initial query gave me 0 results but I changed the following line to this and returned results. "AND LaunchTime = (SELECT MAX(LaunchTime) FROM @OurTable ot2 WHERE ot2.AccountName = ot1.AccountName)"

Comment: Yes, it was a typo! (I editted the query). Thank you!